# Background-color covers previous line

Tags: html, css

How to fix background-color that covers previous line of text (see: http://jsfiddle.net/3uzbV/41/).

```css
div {
 font-family: Charis, serif; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
}
    
span {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div> firstString <span> secoundString </span> thirdString </div>
```

Comment: Make line-height bigger or delete it.

Comment: I can't change line-height and font-size. They have to stay as they are.

Comment: This is closer but still not brilliant: http://jsfiddle.net/f3npa862/

Answer (score 1):

Nest the text inside another element inside that red `span` (here i've used a `b`). That get's us close but there's still an issue with the red bg obscuring the white bg text above it. To resolve that I've used `mix-blend-mode` (which is [not currently supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode))

```css
div {
  font-family: Charis, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

span b {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>... ze cztery. Tymczasem na swym dworze. Nikt go przez okienic szpar i kłopotach, i stanęli kołem. W biegu dotknęła blisko dwadzieści i bawi się strzelbami a Pan świata wie, jak zdrowe oblicz gospodarza, gdy zacność domu, fortuny szczodrot objaśniają wrodzone
  wdzięki i stoi wypisany każdy ksiądz toż samo gada na boku. Panny tuż na wieś i że polskie ubrani wysmukłą postać kształtną i gałęzie drzewa cały las i raptem boczne drzwi od <span><b> płaczącej matki pod Napoleonem, demokrata przyjechał z nieba dochodziło mniej zgorszenia. Ach, ja wam służyć, moje panny Róży a oni tak się i, czyje były, odgadywał. Przypadkiem oczy podniósł, i gestami ją nudzi rzecz długa, choć młodzież teraźniejsza, Że tym bielsze, że nam, kolego! lecz w ziemstwie, potem się czerwieni.</b></span>  Twarzy wówczas nie korzystał dworze jak naoczne świadki. I Wojski z Warszaw mam list, to mówiąc, że.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3g9nvh2a/

Answer (score 0):

I found this great article: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-The-background-color-and-overlapping-rows-inline-element

Add display: inline; to the div tag, and position: relative; to the span tag.

You will get this:

```
div {
    font-family: Charis, serif; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
```

See Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3uzbV/42/

Comment: But the red backgroud still covers text.

Comment: You mean the p and g? Didn't saw that. I don't think there is a better solution. Maybe this: http://jsfiddle.net/3uzbV/43/ But that is all I can think of. Consider an other solution to make the lines smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to the span with a red background:

```
display: inline-block;
```

For example:

```css
div {
    font-family: Charis, serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Litwo! Ojczyzno moja! Ty jesteś jak zdrowie. Ile cię stracił. Dziś człowieka nie biegł sług i dobył książeczkę z liczby kopic, co pod bramę. We dworze jak pieniądze Żydzi. To mówiąc spojrzał zyzem, gdzie mieszkał, dzieckiem będąc, przed laty, nad niego ze cztery. Tymczasem na swym dworze. Nikt go przez okienic szpar i kłopotach, i stanęli kołem. W biegu dotknęła blisko dwadzieści i bawi się strzelbami a Pan świata wie, jak zdrowe oblicz gospodarza, gdy zacność domu, fortuny szczodrot objaśniają wrodzone wdzięki i stoi wypisany każdy ksiądz toż samo gada na boku. Panny tuż na wieś i że polskie ubrani wysmukłą postać kształtną i gałęzie drzewa cały las i raptem boczne drzwi od <span> płaczącej matki pod Napoleonem, demokrata przyjechał z nieba dochodziło mniej zgorszenia. Ach, ja wam służyć, moje panny Róży a oni tak się i, czyje były, odgadywał. Przypadkiem oczy podniósł, i gestami ją nudzi rzecz długa, choć młodzież teraźniejsza, Że tym bielsze, że nam, kolego! lecz w ziemstwie, potem się czerwieni.</span> Twarzy wówczas nie korzystał dworze jak naoczne świadki. I Wojski z Warszaw mam list, to mówiąc, że.</div>
```

Comment: Could you convert jsfiddle to a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple, just use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

In your css for span and it will be done